# Clear cell contents with a WKS IF function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

First, I must admit, I am not a VBA programmer.   I am building a spreadsheet and using the Record Macros to generate VBA to do some of the automated tasks.
I'd like to use the Fill Up and Fill Down function in Excel 2016, (I know this function is available with Get/Transform, but I am wanting to do this with VBA Macros).

My problem is that the Fill up / Fill down doesn't work because it is looking for a blank cell, so the cursor jumps to the bottom of the column in the table without filling in any values. Note, I have filled in the value 0, so I can test for this value to then clear the cell contents.

I'd like to use an If function statement, something like this, to clear out the cells, so the fill up/down will work:   if (a1=0, clear, a1)

I know that syntax is not correct, but can you suggest something like this that I can do with functions?

[image]

[image]

[image][image]

[image][image]

Comment: Have you tought using the "find and replace" dialogue ? Can be accessed by presssing Ctrl+H. Look for 0 and replace with nothing (literally).

Also I am sure there is a way to avoid filling empty cells with "0". Maybe you could show us what you produced with macro recorder.

Comment: Btw you can use F&R on a specific range of cell (given you select it) excluding the rest of your worksheet's content. The selection won't be considered if you search the whole workbook.

Comment: great feedback.  Thank you MrDogme.   Btw, the only reason I filled the value with "0", vs. "" was that it would remind me the cell was not blank.  I was also thinking it would give me the ability to search and replace on the value more easily.  And, it didn't really matter, since I was going to clear it anyway, if I  found a method for doing so.

Comment: Hi MrDogme.   The Find/Replace worked perfect.  Now the issue I am running into is that the next step I am recording in the Macro sequence, is CTRL Down to get to the next non-blank field, which is the company number that I want to Fill Down.  When I click Fill Down, the value for the company number disappears.    I added a screenshot to my original description.

Comment: Could you show us your code? I cannot quite figure what you are aiming to do.

Comment: I posted a screenshot of the columns of data in my original question post.  I'LL ATTACH THE CODE IN A WORD DOCUMENT IN THE MAIN QUESTION AREA

Comment: Hi MrDogme.  I think I figured out what my problem is:  I'm thinking the FillUp or FillDown on the Home tab of Excel works like the FillUp and FillDown Power Query, but it doesn't appear that they do.   It appears they just copy a pattern when when you fill in a direction.   I'm trying to turn a report in spreadsheet format into rows of data records, but I have to "flatten" it out by the subtotals by customer and then have a routing which will automatically fill in the customer number for each row until the next company number changes.